# Use usercontrol id of ascx page in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol.The usercontrol in included in a master page.Now i have yet another page  a aspx page.The aspx page is inheriting the masterpage.So how do i access the id of usercontrol in aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have no direct relation of aspx page with the usercontrol page.In such case make a public function in the master page of type usercontrol

```
public yourusercontrol getucID()
 {
  return usercontrol_id
 }
```

Now you can use this function to get usercontrol id in your aspx.cs page.

```
yourmaster mst = (yourmaster)Page.Master;
 yourusercontrol yuc = mst.getucID();
 //Now do your stuff with yuc
```

I hope it Helps